# Connection refused error on worker node in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, connection, connection-refused

I'm setting up a 2 node cluster in kubernetes. 1 master node and 1 slave node.
After setting up master node I did installation steps of docker, kubeadm,kubelet, kubectl on worker node and then ran the join command. On master node, I see 2 nodes in Ready state (master and worker) but when I try to run any kubectl command on worker node, I'm getting connection refused error as below. I do not see any admin.conf and nothing set in .kube/config . Are these files also needed to be on worker node? and if so how do I get it? How to resolve below error? Appreciate your help

root@kubework:/etc/kubernetes# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

root@kubework:/etc/kubernetes# kubectl cluster-info

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
root@kubework:/etc/kubernetes#

Answer (score 7):

> root@kubework:/etc/kubernetes# kubectl get nodes The connection to the
> server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or
> port?

Kubcetl is by default configured and working on the master.   It requires a kube-apiserver pod and `~/.kube/config`.

For worker nodes, we don’t need to use kube-apiserver but what we want is using the master configuration to pass by it.
To achieve it we have to copy the `~/.kube/config` file from the master to the `~/.kube/config` on the worker. Value `~` with the user executing kubcetl on the worker and master (that may be different of course).
Once that done you could use the `kubectl` command from the worker node exactly as you do that from the master node.

Comment: Thanks David. It is working fine, after copying admin.conf from master to worker node @~/.kube/config

Comment: You are welcome Nitish ! Don't hesitate to accept my answer :)

Comment: @davidxxx Hi David, you mean that in real time scenario its generally not required to run the kubectl command on worker nodes? May I know how moving the config file from mater to worker node fixes the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior even using `kubectl on master node` as non root account, by default this config file is stored for root account in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`:

> To make kubectl work for your non-root user, run these commands, which are also part of the kubeadm init output:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

- Alternatively on the master, if you are the root user, you can run:

```
    export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

> Optionally [Controlling your cluster from machines other than the control-plane node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#optional-controlling-your-cluster-from-machines-other-than-the-control-plane-node)

```
scp root@<control-plane-host>:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf .
kubectl --kubeconfig ./admin.conf get nodes
```

[Note](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#:%7E:text=If%20the%20KUBECONFIG%20environment%20variable,in%20the%20KUBECONFIG%20environment%20variable.):

> The **KUBECONFIG environment variable** holds a list of **kubeconfig files**. For Linux and Mac, the list is colon-delimited. For Windows, the list is semicolon-delimited. The **KUBECONFIG environment variable is not required**. **If the KUBECONFIG environment variable doesn't exist, kubectl uses the default kubeconfig file, $HOME/.kube/config**.

Answer (score 1):

If I try the following commands,

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

getting this error

```
[vikram@node2 ~]$ kubectl version
Error in configuration:
* unable to read client-cert /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem for default-auth due to open /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem: permission denied
* unable to read client-key /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem for default-auth due to open /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem: permission denied
```

Then this works which is really a workaround and not a fix.

```
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf version
```

Was able to fix it by copying the kubelet-client-current.pem from /var/lib/kubelet/pki/ to a location inside $HOME and modifying to reflect the path of the certs in HOME/.kube/config file. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes these files needed. Move these files into respective .kube/config folder on worker nodes.

Comment: Where do I get these files from?I do not have admin.conf file in /etc/Kubernetes/ in worker node And that is the reason I'm getting connection refused error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions which just copy the /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf to ~/.kube/config. But none worked for me.

My OS is ubuntu and is resolved by removing, purging and re-installing the following :

1. sudo dpkg -r kubeadm kubectl
2. sudo dpkg -P kubeadm kubectl
3. sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
4. sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
5. curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" (downloading kubectl again, this actually worked)
6. kubectl get nodes

NAME                       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION

mymaster                  Ready    control-plane,master   31h   v1.20.4

myworker                  Ready                     31h   v1.20.4

Answer (score 0):

Davidxxx's solution worked for me.

In my case, I found out that there is a file that exists in the worker nodes at the following path:

/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf

You can copy this to ~/.kube/config and it works as well. I tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue - I found that my 3 VMs are sharing the same IP (since I was using NAT network on Virtual-box), therefore I switched to Bridge network and have 3 different IPs for 3 different VMs and then followed the installation guide for successful installation of k8s cluster.

Amit